# Bootstrap tour backdrop blinking between steps

Tags: bootstrap-tour

There is an annoying effect in v0.12.0 of Bootstrap tour when activating backdrop.
It works, but once you click next step, **backdrops disapears for a moment and appears again** doing a blink.

**Anyone has a way to deactivate this behavior or a fix for this?**

This is the last version... and it is 1 year old by now.

Comment: can you post a fiddle for that ?

Comment: Sorry... in fiddle only can see v0.11 of the component... will try to host the scripts somewhere else to create a working fiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I did something that worked.
In the "hidestep" function I changed the condition, removing the last or statement:

```
if (step.backdrop) {
    next_step = (iNext != null) && _this.getStep(iNext);

    if (!next_step || !next_step.backdrop /*|| next_step.backdropElement !== step.backdropElement*/) {
              _this._hideOverlayElement(step);
       }
 }
```

**So it ends:**

```
if (step.backdrop) {
        next_step = (iNext != null) && _this.getStep(iNext);

        if (!next_step || !next_step.backdrop ) {
                  _this._hideOverlayElement(step);
           }
     }
```